# Filter specific row in SUM() function in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a system that calculates student marks. Currently, the system calculates the best six subjects, but I want it now to calculate the best 6 inclusive of the mark for English, which means it's the best 5 plus English. The English mark is mandatory that it be included in the calculation.

Here is my code.

```
 UPDATE `students` SET `term_1_avg` =(
     SELECT ROUND (SUM(sub_avg_term1/6)) AS term_1_avg 
     FROM (
         SELECT (sub_avg_term1) 
         FROM marks 
         WHERE marks.student_id = '$student_search_id' 
         ORDER BY sub_avg_term1 DESC LIMIT 6
    ) AS sub
 ) 
 WHERE students.student_id='$student_search_id'
```

How can I do that?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a `UNION` of the 5 top and English. Something like

```
     UPDATE `students` SET `term_1_avg` =(
         SELECT ROUND (SUM(sub_avg_term1/6)) AS term_1_avg 
         FROM (
             (SELECT (sub_avg_term1) 
             FROM marks 
             WHERE marks.student_id = '$student_search_id' 
             AND marks.subject != 'English'
             ORDER BY sub_avg_term1 DESC LIMIT 5)
             UNION
             (SELECT (sub_avg_term1) 
             FROM marks 
             WHERE marks.student_id = '$student_search_id'
             AND marks.subject = 'English')
        ) AS sub
     ) 
     WHERE students.student_id='$student_search_id'
```

assuming `marks` has a `subject` field where you'd find `'English'` as one of the subjects. But you can modify according to whatever your actual structure is.

Comment: thanks but it gives me the  #1221 - Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY error

Comment: better exclude English from the group of five, right? (so you won't potentially get it twice)